# How can specific replacements be formatted in a file?

Tags: regex, python-3.x, file, seek

**sample_file.txt**

```
line1
line2
Apple
line4
line5
line6
line7
line8
line9
Orange
line11
line12
line13
line14
line15
some_text
line17
<fruits name="Pineapple">
line19
line20
line21
</fruits>
line23
<fruits name="Banana">
line25
line26
line27
</fruits>
line29
Apple
line31
Mango
till
line100
```

Above is sample file of 100 lines
1) line3 to line 10, Apple followed by Orange should be removed
2) line 16, `some_text` should be replaced by `Found data`
3) Tag  should be commented.
4) Tag  should be removed.
5) Apple followed by Mango shouldn't be altered.

how can we achieve this in python?
using `reg-ex` or `seek` ?

**output_file.txt**

```
line1
line2
line11
line12
line13
line14
line15
Found data
line17
<!--<fruits name="Pineapple">
line19
line20
line21
</fruits>-->
line23
line29
Apple
line31
Mango
till
line100
```

**Code:**

```
import re

with open('sample_file.txt', 'r') as file:
    filedata = file.read()

filedata = filedata.replace("some_text", "Found data")

with open('output_file.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write(filedata)
```

Comment: You could do this very easily with Regular-Expression, but this smells a lot like homework to me. Could you provide the code you've tried out yourself already? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @HampusLarsson I could only try for replacing, pasted code above. I'm  not that expert in reg-ex or file-handling()by line numbers, seek etc). Could you please help me for rest of the scenarios ?

Comment: @HampusLarsson If i provide regex as "<fruits name=\"Pineapple"\>.*<\/fruits>" , it covers all the tags. How do match it for <fruits name="Pineapple"> followed by corresponding </fruits> not of other <fruits> tag. Since, it's a file how do you apply it for multi-lines ?

Comment: @HampusLarsson any help ?